# Number of Common sub sequences of two strings

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

Revisiting Longest Common Subsequence, I was wondering what is the number of common subsequences of 2 strings. I tried to formulate a recurrent relation :
DP[i][j] represents the number of subsequences ending at max i in first string and j in second. 
Recurrent relation being :

`DP[i][j]= DP[i-1][j-1] + DP[i][j-1] + DP[i-1][j]` when `A[i]==B[j]`  (A is my first string while B is the second)

and

```
DP[i][j]=DP[i-1][j]+DP[i][j-1] other wise
```

It is not giving correct results!

Explanation if A[i]==B[j], then , We can add A[i] to every common subsequence till i-1 and j-1 to form DP[i-1][j-1] new subsequences. Also We have to add the subsequences formed by dropping the last character from each string.

other wise we can only add the ways by dropping last characters!

If someone can correct this recurrence? Morover , I will love to see a formal proof.(Just getting into the habit of seeing a formal proof(You can provide a hint to prove it myself too.))

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention the base cases I was considering

`DP[i][0]=1` for all i in length of A

and
`DP[0][j]=1` for all j in length of B

and also

```
DP[0][0]=1
```

(denoting empty subsequence)

Comment: It seems that DP[i-1][j] and DP[i][j-1] shall have sum common subsequences which will be double counted (DP[i-1][j-1]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DP[i-1][j]` and `DP[i][j-1]` shall have `DP[i-1][j-1]` common sub-sequences which will be double counted.

Change your recurrence to:

`DP[i][j]= DP[i][j-1] + DP[i-1][j]` when `A[i]==B[j]`

and

`DP[i][j]=DP[i-1][j]+DP[i][j-1]-DP[i-1][j-1]` other wise

**Explanation:**
In your original relations, I have just subtracted a term `DP[i-1][j-1]`. This is because `DP[i][j-1]` and `DP[i-1][j]` both include `DP[i-1][j-1]`. Since we are adding these two terms, the term `DP[i-1][j-1]` is getting double counted, so we need to subtract it once.

Comment: Can you please explain  more about the solution?

Comment: @nikhiljain What don't you understand?

Comment: Can you generalise the formula may be for four ?

Comment: Can you generalise the formula may be for four ? @user1990169

Answer (score 3):

```
#define MAX_LEN 101
string s1;
string s2;
int N1;
int N2;
int dp[MAX_LEN][MAX_LEN];
int GetCommomSubsequencesCount()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= N1; i++)//N1 is size of 1st string
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= N2; j++)//N2 is size of 2nd string
        {
            dp[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= N1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= N2; j++)
        {
            if (s1[i - 1] == s2[j - 1])
            {
                dp[i][j] = 1 + dp[i][j - 1] + dp[i - 1][j];                    
            }
            else
            {
                dp[i][j] =  dp[i][j - 1] + dp[i - 1][j] - dp[i-1][j-1];
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[N1][N2];
}
```

**Explanation :**

dp[i][j] is the number of common sub-sequences for two strings with size i and j respectively

**Case 1 : s1[i-1] == s2[j-1]**

All previous common sub-sequences are doubled as they get appended by one more character.
Both dp[i][j-1] and dp[i-1][j] contain dp[i-1][j-1] and hence it gets added two times in our recurrence which takes care of doubling of count of all previous common sub-sequences.
Addition of 1 in recurrence is for the latest character match : common sub-sequence made up of s1[i-1] and s2[j-1]

**Case 2: s1[i-1] != s2[j-1]**

Here we subtract dp[i-1][j-1] once because it is present in both  dp[i][j - 1] and  dp[i - 1][j] and gets added twice.

***I reckon these recurrences are easier to absorb as they do not rely on empty sub-sequences.***